# how to handle race conditions in class components?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose there is a component where ask server to do some search and response will be rendered. How to ensure most recent request's response is rendered even if server side for any reason answers in different ordering? I'm not asking about cancelling previous request since it's not always possible with reasonable efforts.

```
 onClick = () => {
   apiCall(this.state.searchQuery).then(items => this.setState({ items }));
 };
```

Is there elegant way to handle that? By now I know few approaches:

1. disabling button till request comes(provides bad experiences in large amount of cases - say for searching while typing)
2. checking inside `then()` if request's params matches `this.props`/`this.state` data(does not handle case when we intentionally forced new search with same query - say by pressing Enter/clicking "Search" button)

```
onClick = () => {
  const searchQuery = this.state.searchQuery;
  apiCall(searchQuery)
    .then(items => 
      this.state.searchQuery === searchQuery 
        && this.setState({ items })
  );
};
```

3. marking requests somehow and checking if it's latest(works, but looks too verboose especially if there are few requests we need to check)

```
 searchQueryIndex = 0;
 onClick = () => {
   this.searchQueryIndex++;
   const index = this.searchQueryIndex;
   apiCall(this.state.searchQuery)
     .then(items =>  
       this.searchQueryIndex === searchQueryIndex 
         && this.setState({ items })
   );
 };
```

I'd call that trio "ugly, broken and messy".

Is there something such clear way as hooks allow:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const isCanceled = false;
   apiCall(searchQuery).then(items => !isCanceled && setItems(items));
   return () => {isCanceled = true;};
 }, [searchQuery])
```

Comment: So you;d like the promise to resolve only when it was the user's latest click? Something like [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L346-L392)?

Comment: @HMR, yes, that's like my #3 but moved into external helper/library. may you know alternatives? sure, it works but looks rather complicated.

Comment: It would clean up your 3rd option and look a lot like the useEffect, `last` can be a property of your class: `last=onlyLastRequestedPromise("search")` and in the promise or anywhere you call your api: `this.last(apiCall(this.state.searchQuery)).then(items => items!==CANCELLED && this.setState({ items }));` You have to [adjust](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L383) `onlyLastRequestedPromise` to resolve with a constant named CANCELLED.

Comment: actually, I meant `searchQueryIndex` is class property, but I see, it is not clear. Could you run official answer with your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClick handler suggest a class component since you use `this` and `this.setState`:

```
onClick = () => {
  apiCall(this.state.searchQuery).then(items =>
    this.setState({ items })
  );
};
```

I adjusted `onlyLastRequestedPromise` to take a function that will return something (you can return Promise.reject('cancelled') or anything).

```
const onlyLastRequestedPromise = (promiseIds => {
  const whenResolve = (
    promise,
    id,
    promiseID,
    resolveValue,
    whenCancelled = () => Promise.reject('cancelled')
  ) => {
    if (promise !== undefined) {
      //called by user adding a promise
      promiseIds[id] = {};
    } else {
      //called because promise is resolved
      return promiseID === promiseIds[id]
        ? Promise.resolve(resolveValue)
        : whenCancelled(resolveValue);
    }
    return (function(currentPromiseID) {
      return promise.then(function(result) {
        return whenResolve(
          undefined,
          id,
          currentPromiseID,
          result
        );
      });
    })(promiseIds[id]);
  };
  return (id = 'general', whenCancelled) => promise =>
    whenResolve(
      promise,
      id,
      undefined,
      undefined,
      whenCancelled
    );
})({});
```

A class example on how to use it:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  CANCELLED = {};
  last = onlyLastRequestedPromise(
    'search',
    () => this.CANCELLED
  );
  onSearch = () => {
    this.last(apiCall(this.state.searchQuery)).then(
      items =>
        items !== this.CANCELLED && this.setState({ items })
    );
  };
  changeAndSearch = e => {
    this.setState(
      {}, //state with new value
      () => this.onSearch() //onSearch after state update
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchButton onClick={this.onSearch} />
        <Other onChange={this.changeAndSearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I agree it's a lot of code but since you put most of the implementation in the lib it should not clutter your components.

If you had a functional component you could create the last function with useRef:

```
//
function ComponentContainer(props) {
  const CANCELLED = useRef({});
  const last = useRef(
    onlyLastRequestedPromise('search', () => CANCELLED)
  );
  const [searchQuery,setSearchQuery] = useState({});
  const mounted = useIsMounted();
  const onSearch = useCallback(
    last(apiCall(searchQuery)).then(
      items =>
        items !== CANCELLED &&
        mounted.current &&
        //do something with items
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: "Your onClick handler suggest a class component" actually it was in title :)

Comment: @skyboyer yes, you're right, I was confused by the useEffect hook, that does look cleaner but will do something on render and not do something on click.

Comment: goal was to figure out how to get such clean approach, as `useEffect` allows, with class components. do you think I better to rewrite question to make it more clear?

Comment: @skyboyer No, I think most people get it. If you had functional components you could write last as a custom hook: `const last = useLast(apiCall);` and onSearch would just be: `last(searchQuery).then(result=>do something with result)` Building the last and mounted check in useLast hook.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to utilize closure to mimic "just ignore that" approach from hooks' world:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  const ignorePrevRequest = () => {}; // empty function by default

  loadSomeData() {
    this.ignorePrevRequest(); 
    let cancelled = false;
    this.ignorePrevRequest = () => { cancelled = true; }; // closure comes to play
    doSomeCall().then(data => !cancelled && this.setState({ data }))
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty neat way! But as `setState` is batched it would be better to move the `canceled` check into `setState` itself. So the corresponding line would be `doSomeCall().then(data => this.setState(() => !cancelled ? { data } : {}))`.

Comment: @Mindxxxd could you please elaborate? Since it's async operation there is no another `this.setState` call that could be batched together with existing one.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) react may batch multiple `setState` calls into one update and one rerender. The batching does not depend on "where" it was called but "when" it was called. Ah, yeah I see. As long as the calling order stays the same (which it will) it really doesent matter if we move the check into the `setState` itself.

Comment: right! btw batching happens always in React 18+. But since here is always just single call, it does not really matter.